# Android Tablet video stream

Tags: android, video, stream, usb, tablet

I'd like to see the live videos of my GoPro directly onto my tablet (Samsung Tab A).
The GoPro has an HDMI Output so I put this [device](https://www.lambda-tek.de/StarTech-com-USB2HDCAPM~sh/B2638579&origin=gbaseDE19.8?gclid=CI6v-ZKC588CFWYo0wodq1cN2w) to convert from HDMI to USB. Is it possible to see the videostream with some kind of applications?

I installed VLC and Cheese but they doesn't show any image or stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gopro.smarty). Don't forget check compatibility with yours GoPro camera.